# Is there pre-trained doc2vec model in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Is there any pre-trained doc2Vec models, trained in python 3 on news articles data.

Most of the models that I am finding are in older versions. And, it's difficult to implement in python 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, I'm afraid, no. Not at this time. Also, I think the python 2 models that are available are `word2vec`, not `doc2vec`